# Assign new post author IF another user in custom field on post transition

Tags: php, functions, filters, hooks, author

I have a post that is being made on behalf of someone else - so a team member adds the post for the author using a frontend form, but when the post status changes to publish, I want the selected user in the custom field box to be updated as the post author.

And I don't want to go into the admin dashboard to update the author, as the team member does not have access and it would cause a lot of unneeded admin!

I thought I could use the publish_post hook (or 'transferring_post' for me as I use custom post statuses). But then I found:

```
add_filter("the_author", "change_author");
function change_author($author){
$author "NEW AUTHOR!";
return $author; }
```

However, how do I then update this to only fire on a post transition to my custom post status 'transferring'?

Edit (for anyone looking to do something similar - this works)

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status','transfer_to_review_transition_post_status',10, 3);
function transfer_to_review_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post){
    if (($old_status == 'transferring') && ($new_status == 'review') && ($post->post_type == 'research')){
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $oldauthor = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
        $newauthor = rwmb_meta( 'academicinterview_transfer_author_to_academic', '', $post_id );
    if (!empty($newauthor) && ($newauthor != $oldauthor) ) {
    $postarr = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_author' => $newauthor,
    );
        wp_update_post($postarr);
    }
    };}

    }
```

Comment: Could it not have that author from the beginning instead of changing author on publish?

Comment: Hey Tom - thanks for the suggestion -  do you mean if the author ($preparer) who is writing the post on behalf of the public author ($publicauthor) changes the post author on the WP backend? That would certainly work if I had a normal setup. But the $preparer are also external - so I have multiple user dashboards to try to make it an easier user experience for the $preparer. So they also submit via frontend. Plus I only want the post author to transition when the $preparer is ready.

Comment: No, if Alice is writing a post on behalf of Bob, then the author would be and always will have been Bob. It would never have Alice as the author, and no switching would occur because none is necessary. I'm not sure why Alice would ever be the author, it sounds like you're trying to automate a solution to a different problem you haven't shared, aka _Alice can't see posts she's writing on other peoples behalf in your custom dashboards unless the author is set to Alice_. That sounds like an easier problem to solve.

Comment: it also sounds like you have no system for writing articles on behalf of other people, other than the manual process to changing the author on publish. The problem is that to solve the original problem you would need to know which posts are written on behalf of people, but you can't avoid that problem because you need to solve it to automate your workaround. AKA How does it know that you want Alices posts to change their author on publish to Bob? And if you know how to determine that, why not just show those in the dashboard anyway?

Comment: It would make more sense for the dropdown to set the author not a custom field, then to store the proxy author who actually writes the post in the custom field so that you can find those posts when they view their dashboards

Comment: Hi Tom, I think you are thinking more logically than me. I have a flow and at one moment that flow changes to a transferring status - when this happens, it is ready to transfer - but I want a memory of Alice (this saves as a custom field) - and yes I wish to automate this. I have just now been trying to work on some code, maybe explains better:

Comment: add_action( 'transition_post_status','transfer_to_review_transition_post_status',10, 3);
function transfer_to_review_transition_post_status($new_status, $old_status, $post){
 if ( ($old_status === 'transferring') && ($new_status === 'review') && ($post->post_type === 'research') ) {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
  $oldauthor = $post_id->post_author;
  $newauthor = rwmb_meta( 'academicinterview_transfer_author_to_academic', '', $post_id ); 
  if (!$newauthor ) {
  $my_post = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'author' => $newauthor,
    );
 wp_update_post( $my_post );
    };}

Comment: Yes - your last comment, exactly! I just don't know how to do that..

Comment: please use the edit link to add code to your question, not comments, your code was mangled and broken by the commenting

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. Added to question in an edit